Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 124--124
I am plotting graphs into Overleaf online and some graphs are working, and some are not. In one whole section all the graphs are correct, but in another only the caption shows up. I've noticed in only the broken section the error code "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 124--124" shows up. The code is exactly the same between sections, save the "sweepfolder" which is specified before hand. The folder structure for each respective section is also the same. Also, not all the graphs don't show up. Only about 9 of 10 graphs in this section don't show, and the ones that do show are picked at random (are not the same graphs). I know this is not a common problem, but any ideas are helpful, and I am happy to provide any extra information.
Sample Code for 1 section:

\def\optimizedmetric{MinMaxed_PL}

\def\frontname{Appendix-G/MinMax_vs_CR_0_vs_CR_-20_vs_CR_90/\sweepfolder/\optimizedmetric/}
% Loop through a list of image filenames

\foreach \q in {Coefficient_of_Power,Total/Coefficient_of_Power,Upper/Coefficient_of_Power,Lower/Coefficient_of_Power,Coefficient_of_Thrust,Total/Coefficient_of_Thrust,Upper/Coefficient_of_Thrust,Lower/Coefficient_of_Thrust,Figure_of_Merit,Total/Figure_of_Merit,Upper/Figure_of_Merit,Lower/Figure_of_Merit,Power_Loading,Total/Power_Loading,Upper/Power_Loading,Lower/Power_Loading,Microphone_8_A-Weighted_SPL,OASPL/Microphone_8_A-Weighted_SPL,Tonal/Microphone_8_A-Weighted_SPL,Broadband/Microphone_8_A-Weighted_SPL,Microphone_8_SPL,OASPL/Microphone_8_SPL,Tonal/Microphone_8_SPL,Broadband/Microphone_8_SPL}

{
    \foreach \n in {       
        %insert filenames        
        \frontname \q \ending
        } {
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{\n}
            \caption{\n}
            \label{fig:\n}
        \end{figure}
        \n
    }
}      %line 124

The correct section:
The blank section: 
Randomly picked graph:


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Update: the problem does not occur if I use "\foreach \q in {Coefficient_of_Power,Coefficient_of_Thrust,Figure_of_Merit,Power_Loading,Microphone_8_A-Weighted_SPL,Microphone_8_SPL}". I.e. without the nested folders that include "/". However, I still want to use these folders without moving everything manually. Anyone know a work around?

please, we need you to complete your snippet. right now, my guess is that \foreach is from pgf. if so, you may need to protect the /. but I'd expect you to get errors in that case with or without the / because you are not expanding the list before passing it to \foreach in the inner loop. so maybe \foreach is not from pgf and you've defined it some other way? and you have all kinds of other non-standard macros here which I can't even guess how you're defining them ,,,

note that the underfull box is not an error. it's just a warning. I suspect you do have errors in your document, but you've not shown them here.
